# SQL database transfer from web server hosting to sql server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I read the other posts about copying and using "Red Gate", but can anyone give a detailed tutorial on how to transfer the database from my web hosting to sql server 2000?

Comment: The simplest thing to do is probably backup, download the backup and restore on the new server. However, you must make sure your source and target servers are running the same version of sql server, or at least the target server is not running a lower version then the source version.

Comment: It depends on what are you using on the web server. The web server also uses SQL Server or uses another type, like MySQL or PostgreSQL?

Comment: SQL server 2000? Maybe 2012? I cant imagine you want to use 2000 as that is a security risk as it reached end of life(i.e. no more updates) in 2013 somewhere.